# iOS SDK - issue changing UIPicker font size. strange behavior

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, conditional-statements, uipickerview

I can not understand why this code does not work

I am using this delegate method to resize the font (i dont bother showing that because its not relevant)

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;
```

this is a multi picker.  i have three components.  When I run the code with a conditional statement using else, it makes section 0 match section 2.  I can't explain this

```
NSLog(@"%i", component); // only prints, 0, 1, 2
NSString *theString = @"";
if(component == 0){
    theString = [_phosType objectAtIndex:row];
}
if(component == 1){
    theString = [_quantity objectAtIndex:row];
} else {                                        // THIS CAUSES PROBLEMS.
    theString = [_units objectAtIndex:row];
}
pickerViewLabel.text = theString;
```

this one works.. what gives!

```
NSLog(@"%i", component); // only prints, 0, 1, 2
NSString *theString = @"";
if(component == 0){
    theString = [_phosType objectAtIndex:row];
}
if(component == 1){
    theString = [_quantity objectAtIndex:row];
}

if(component == 2){                            // THIS WORKS!  BUT WHY?!
    theString = [_units objectAtIndex:row];
}
pickerViewLabel.text = theString;
```

why do i need to explicitly ask if component is 2?  i can see when I NSLog component that it never equals anything other than 0 1 or 2.  I'm using 'else' everywhere else in the code and having the problem.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: this is what happens when you program too late at night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `component=0` check what happens in this if statement:

```
if(component == 1){
    theString = [_quantity objectAtIndex:row];
}
else {                                       
   theString = [_units objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

You can see that else block will be executed because it will evaluate `if(component == 1)` as false and else block will be executed. 
But if `component=0` this block will also be executed:

```
if(component == 0){
    theString = [_phosType objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

So, when `component=0` `theString` will be set two times: in the first if block and in the else block. And final `theString` value will be the one set in the else block.

Try this instead:

```
if(component == 0){
    theString = [_phosType objectAtIndex:row];
}
else if(component == 1){
    theString = [_quantity objectAtIndex:row];
}
else {                         
    theString = [_units objectAtIndex:row];
}
```